# Parse page with HTML DOM after authorization with CURL

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am look for a solution how to parse page using Simple HTML DOM Parser after authorization using CURL.

Now I have two working parts of code: CURL authorization and Simple HTML DOM Parser

1) authorization using CURL

```
$data = array();
$data['name'] = 'name';
$data['pass'] = 'pass';
$data['loginbtnUp'] = '1';
$data['submit_flag'] = '1';
$data['rand'] = microtime(true);
$data['formSubmitted']=1;

$post_str = '';
foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
    $post_str .= $key.'='.urlencode($val).'&';
}
$post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);
$cookie_file = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.page.com/' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$response = curl_exec($ch );

echo $response;

curl_close($ch);
```

2) and Simple HTML DOM Parser

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
  'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17'
)));
$html = str_get_html( file_get_contents('http://page.com/user1', false, $context) );

foreach($html->find('img[width="200"]') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';
```

My question is how to combine those parts of code for parsing  page that have access only for authorized users. I need just once to logged in and then parse different pages which is available for  authorized users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have logged in with CURL, which is great, but CURL now holds your cookies in your `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` file.

In order for the site to continue to serve you protected content, you need to continue to serve it with the session cookie that it gave you after logging in.

Therefore, your additional requests to password-protected pages should be using CURL much in the way that your login process did (except, obviously, you don't need to `POST`, you can just `GET`):

```
$ch = curl_init('https://login.page.com/protectedcontent');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = str_get_html($response);
```

Comment: I need just once to logged in and then parse different pages which is available for  authorized users

Comment: I know that. Which is exactly what this code does, so you should try it. This code isn't logging in again. It is using CURL to fetch protected content.

Comment: Replace your `str_get_html` line in the second piece of code that you posted with this, and obviously replace the URL to whatever page you're trying to fetch from

Comment: result is whole lightweight page version without tags that i need, and 
User-Agent is not used

Comment: add some code: 
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) ' .
            'Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
but now i get whole protected page

Comment: Alright well I can't follow what you're saying, to be honest. I have told you what you should need to know to get this done. What you were missing was using `curl` to make sure that you send the cookies with every future request. Be SURE you are using the same `COOKIEJAR` and `COOKIEFILE` when you retrieve the pages as you do when you login. That's about all I can do for you now.

Comment: ok, I try to be sequential ), I use our code and get whole protected page content https://login.page.com/protectedcontent  But goal is to parse page and get part of page

Comment: It's `file_get_contents` you need to replace with curl, not `str_get_html`. No offense but this seems to be beyond your abilities and you should consider hiring help.

Comment: @pguardiario That's correct. What I was implying was that (s)he needed to replace _that line_. Not necessarily that particular function call.

Comment: @Colin, I know you meant that, I was just hoping to clarify.

Comment: Colin Morelli, thank you, its work, I have some mistakes in my code